# Apache-Mina FTPServer Database User Manager failure

Tags: java, windows, apache, jdbc, javabeans

I'm attempting to set up a windows-based FTP server using Apache FTPServer, however I keep running into the same issue whenever I use db-user-manager as opposed to the file-user-manager. We have close to 6,000 users in our database that we want to migrate over to windows, so the file-user-manager just would be inadequate (as the size would be IMMENSE). I already created the local SQL server using WAMP and set it up for Apache FTP to use, and have a script to query / copy / organize the users in the remote database to the local one on a daily basis.

The issue that i'm having is that for whatever reason, Apache FTPServer keeps giving me the following error whenever I run the program:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 27 in XML document from file [c:\apache-ftpserver-1.0.5\res\conf\ftpd-full.xml] is invalid; 
nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The prefix "beans" for element "beans:bean" is not bound.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:404)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:342)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:310)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:143)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:178)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:149)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:212)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:113)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:80)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:123)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:423)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:353)
    at org.springframework.context.support.FileSystemXmlApplicationContext.<init>(FileSystemXmlApplicationContext.java:140)
    at org.springframework.context.support.FileSystemXmlApplicationContext.<init>(FileSystemXmlApplicationContext.java:84)
    at org.apache.ftpserver.main.CommandLine.getConfiguration(CommandLine.java:132)
    at org.apache.ftpserver.main.CommandLine.main(CommandLine.java:56)
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The prefix "beans" for element "beans:bean" is not bound.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:195)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:174)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:388)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:318)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:310)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2755)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:648)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:140)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:511)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:808)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:737)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:119)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:235)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:284)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultDocumentLoader.loadDocument(DefaultDocumentLoader.java:75)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:396)
    ... 15 more
```

- I downloaded the proper DBCP basic data source file from http://commons.apache.org/dbcp/ and the mysql connector `(version 5.1.6 at that time)` from http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/ and put all the file into the common\lib folder as instructed.
- I made sure to remove the other user management code "file-user-manager"

I still don't get it... why doesn't it work?

Here is my xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!--
        Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
        contributor license agreements. See the NOTICE file distributed with
        this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
        The ASF licenses this file to you under the Apache License, Version
        2.0 (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
        with the License. You may obtain a copy of the License at
        http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0 Unless required by
        applicable law or agreed to in writing, software distributed under the
        License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR
        CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied. See the License for
        the specific language governing permissions and limitations under the
        License.
    -->
<server xmlns="http://mina.apache.org/ftpserver/spring/v1"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
       http://mina.apache.org/ftpserver/spring/v1 http://mina.apache.org/ftpserver/ftpserver-1.0.xsd    
       "
    id="Prometheus">
    <listeners>
        <nio-listener name="default" port="2121" />
    </listeners>
    <db-user-manager>
        <data-source>
            <beans:bean class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" >
                <beans:property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
                <beans:property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/apache_test" />
                <beans:property name="username" value="admin" />
                <beans:property name="password" value="password" />
            </beans:bean>
        </data-source>
        <insert-user>INSERT INTO FTP_USER (userid, userpassword,
            homedirectory, enableflag, writepermission, idletime, uploadrate,
            downloadrate) VALUES ('{userid}', '{userpassword}',
            '{homedirectory}',
            {enableflag}, {writepermission}, {idletime},
            {uploadrate},
            {downloadrate})
        </insert-user>
            <update-user>UPDATE FTP_USER SET
                userpassword='{userpassword}',homedirectory='{homedirectory}',enableflag={enableflag},writepermission={writepermission},idletime={idletime},uploadrate={uploadrate},downloadrate={downloadrate}
                WHERE userid='{userid}'
        </update-user>
            <delete-user>DELETE FROM FTP_USER WHERE userid = '{userid}'
        </delete-user>
            <select-user>SELECT userid, userpassword, homedirectory,
                enableflag, writepermission, idletime, uploadrate, downloadrate,
                maxloginnumber, maxloginperip FROM
                FTP_USER WHERE userid = '{userid}'
        </select-user>
            <select-all-users>SELECT userid FROM FTP_USER ORDER BY userid
        </select-all-users>
            <is-admin>SELECT userid FROM FTP_USER WHERE userid='{userid}'
                AND
                userid='admin'
        </is-admin>
            <authenticate>SELECT userpassword from FTP_USER WHERE
                userid='{userid}'</authenticate>
    </db-user-manager>
</server>
```

---

New error after making edit suggested by Femi:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.apache.ftpserver.usermanager.DbUserManagerFactory#0': Cannot create inner bean 
'org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource#c832d2' of type [org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource] while setting bean property 'dataSource'; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource#c832d2' defined in file 
[C:\apache-ftpserver-1.0.5\res\conf\ftpd-full.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/pool/KeyedObjectPoolFactory
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:230)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:117)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1245)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1010)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:472)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:380)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:264)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:221)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:261)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:185)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:164)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:429)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:729)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:381)
        at org.springframework.context.support.FileSystemXmlApplicationContext.<init>(FileSystemXmlApplicationContext.java:140)
        at org.springframework.context.support.FileSystemXmlApplicationContext.<init>(FileSystemXmlApplicationContext.java:84)
        at org.apache.ftpserver.main.CommandLine.getConfiguration(CommandLine.java:132)
        at org.apache.ftpserver.main.CommandLine.main(CommandLine.java:56)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource#c832d2' defined in file [C:\apache-ftpserver-1.0.5\res\conf\ftpd-full.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/pool/KeyedObjectPoolFactory
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:883)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:839)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:440)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:380)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:219)
        ... 19 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/pool/KeyedObjectPoolFactory
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2389)
        at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2699)
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:1985)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:54)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:877)
        ... 25 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.pool.KeyedObjectPoolFactory
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
        ... 31 more
```

---

New error after second change suggested by Femi:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.apache.ftpserver.FtpServerFactory#0': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)' while setting bean property 'u
serManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#1': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springfr
amework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public org.apache.ftpserver.ftplet.UserManager org.apache.ftpserver.usermanager.DbUserManagerFactory.createUserManager()] threw exce
ption; nested exception is org.apache.ftpserver.FtpServerConfigurationException: Failed to open connection to user database
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:230)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:122)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1245)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1010)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:472)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:380)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:264)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:221)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:261)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:185)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:164)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:429)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:729)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:381)
        at org.springframework.context.support.FileSystemXmlApplicationContext.<init>(FileSystemXmlApplicationContext.java:140)
        at org.springframework.context.support.FileSystemXmlApplicationContext.<init>(FileSystemXmlApplicationContext.java:84)
        at org.apache.ftpserver.main.CommandLine.getConfiguration(CommandLine.java:132)
        at org.apache.ftpserver.main.CommandLine.main(CommandLine.java:56)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#1': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.
BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public org.apache.ftpserver.ftplet.UserManager org.apache.ftpserver.usermanager.DbUserManagerFactory.createUserManager()] threw exception; nested exceptio
n is org.apache.ftpserver.FtpServerConfigurationException: Failed to open connection to user database
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:444)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:903)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:817)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:440)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:380)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:219)
        ... 19 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public org.apache.ftpserver.ftplet.UserManager org.apache.ftpserver.usermanager.DbUserManagerFactory.createUs
erManager()] threw exception; nested exception is org.apache.ftpserver.FtpServerConfigurationException: Failed to open connection to user database
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:127)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:435)
        ... 26 more
Caused by: org.apache.ftpserver.FtpServerConfigurationException: Failed to open connection to user database
        at org.apache.ftpserver.usermanager.impl.DbUserManager.<init>(DbUserManager.java:103)
        at org.apache.ftpserver.usermanager.DbUserManagerFactory.createUserManager(DbUserManagerFactory.java:89)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:115)
        ... 27 more
Caused by: org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Access denied for user 'user'@'localhost' (using password: YES))
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1549)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1388)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1044)
        at org.apache.ftpserver.usermanager.impl.DbUserManager.createConnection(DbUserManager.java:307)
        at org.apache.ftpserver.usermanager.impl.DbUserManager.<init>(DbUserManager.java:98)
        ... 33 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'user'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1055)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:956)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3491)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3423)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:910)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.secureAuth411(MysqlIO.java:3923)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1273)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2031)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:718)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:46)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:406)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:302)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:282)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DriverConnectionFactory.createConnection(DriverConnectionFactory.java:38)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnectionFactory.makeObject(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:582)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.validateConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1556)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1545)
        ... 37 more
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its not a DBCP problem, its a Spring configuration problem. Change the top of your XML file to include the spring bean definitions and I think you will be fine.

```
<server xmlns="http://mina.apache.org/ftpserver/spring/v1"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
       http://mina.apache.org/ftpserver/spring/v1 http://mina.apache.org/ftpserver/ftpserver-1.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd"
    id="Prometheus">
```

You might need to change the `2.0.xsd` at the end to `3.0.xsd` depending on the version of Spring that ships with MINA FTPServer.

Comment: You need to also get commons-pool. Download the jar from http://commons.apache.org/pool/ and put it in the same place as you put the DBCP jar.

Comment: I think Apache just hates me or something... caused a new error this time - updated  / added it to the post again.

Comment: Did you get and install the commons pool jar file in the correct place?

Comment: yes, i put them all in .\common\lib  --  sorry, took me a little while to copy the error output. its up now.

Comment: Ah, that's a different problem: `org.apache.ftpserver.FtpServerConfigurationException: Failed to open connection to user database` tells you the problem. It can't connect to your database. Figure out what you did wrong with either your firewall or your MySQL config.

Comment: ahh stupid me had the host set to "Any Host" / "%" instead of "localhost".

Thanks mate, this worked!

Answer (score 2):

Instead of (or in addition to) the `commons-pool-1.6` (link above), install in `common/lib` the `commons-dbcp-1.4` the 3 jar files.

http://commons.apache.org/dbcp/download_dbcp.cgi

That worked for me.